# How do I use custom fonts for labelling in Geoserver?

Tags: geoserver, font

I want to use a custom font I have downloaded from the web with Geoserver for my labels. How do I specify the location of my font so that the font-family css parameter can read it?

Geoserver 2.1.4

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You put your custom TTF-fonts in the catalog *styles* which are located in your data directory.

Then you need to *Clear Resource Cache* under *Server Status* so that the font will be loaded by the server!

This is a new functionality from 2.1.x.

Comment: I did the above steps no luck so far, do I just specify in my sld as <sld:Font><sld:CssParameter name="font-family">"fontName".ttf</sld:CssParameter></sld:Font>? Or is there a special way of specifying?

Comment: Apolologies for the above comment, I had got the font name wrong. Also you do not require the .ttf extension.

Comment: Two additions on this: 1. Workspaces also contain a directory named "styles" but you need to place the font files next to the global styles (data directory/styles). 2. Using the filename will not work, it has to be the font's name. You can check installed names by using the REST-API, see https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/rest/fonts.html.

Answer (score 3):

Puting my font files (*.ttf) to (...)/geoserver/data/styles still works in version 2.6?
I put files there, cleared resources cache and in full list of available fonts they don't exist.

Comment: Did you get this resolved?

Comment: and for linux users: in addition to the /styles folder in the gdal-data directory you'll have to place fonts somewhere like **/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_144/jre/lib/fonts** then restart Geoserver before they're visible in the Geoserver GUI *"Fonts available to JVM"*

Answer (score 1):

Moving the ttf's into the data_dir of GeoServer didn't work out for me, too. So, I simply put them into `C:/Windows/Fonts`, cleared the ressource cache and voilà! Now they are available on GeoServer.

My environment: **Windows Server 2008 R2** with **GeoServer 2.10.1**.